# LoadLibrary relative Path

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll

I trie to load a dll into my application. The dll and all dependend dll's are stored in the application directory.

First i tried to load with this:

```
HINSTANCE dllInstance = LoadLibrary(L"opc_ua_client_dlld.dll");
```

This is not working.

```
HINSTANCE dllInstance = LoadLibraryEx(L"opc_ua_client_dlld.dll",NULL,LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_APPLICATION_DIR);
```

This is also not working

Only if I give a absolute path to the dll, the application tries to load the dll but I get an error that the dependend dll's are not found.

How can load from a relative path?

Comment: Considering that VS2010 is not the newest Version, the question arises on which OS you are executing your program ("Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Vista, and Windows Server 2008:  This value requires [KB2533623](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2533623) to be installed.")

Comment: If you have no idea what dependent DLLs are missing then use SysInternals' Process Monitor.  You see the app searching for it and not finding it.

Comment: The extensive Remarks section in the [LoadLibrary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation describes how it searches for a DLL when you provide a relative path.  The first place it looks is next to the current image.  I second using [ProcessMonitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to try to track down your dependency issues.

Comment: I found the Problem. I am using a UnitTest and the active directory is not the debug directory in my solution. So  I set with [code] SetDllDirectory(L"Path to Dll");[\code] the directory where to search for the dlls